# Replace a checkbox by a Yes/No dropdown box in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I have a checkbox on my shipment page called Special Labels.

The client wants the field to display as a Yes/No dropdown box or something in that line.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could handle this a couple of ways:

Option 1 (PXDropdown):

Create a string field for a Yes/No dropdown and use its value to set your boolean field:

```
        #region ActiveString
        public abstract class activeString : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXString]
        [PXDefault("false")]
        [YesNo.List()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Active")]
        public virtual string ActiveString { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Active
        public abstract class active : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXDefault(true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Active", Visible = false, Enabled = false)]
        public virtual bool? Active {
            get { return Convert.ToBoolean(this.ActiveString ?? "false"); }
            set { value = Convert.ToBoolean(this.ActiveString ?? "false"); }
        }
        #endregion
```

The dropdown ASPX markup:

```
        <px:PXDropdown ID="edActive" runat="server" 
                DataField="ActiveString" Size="XS" >
            <AutoCallBack Command="Save" Target="form">
            </AutoCallBack>
        </px:PXDropdown>
```

Option 2 (PXSelector):

Create a small table in the database for a selector, such as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsrTrueFalse]
(
    [BoolValue] bit NOT NULL,
    [TextValue] [varchar](3) NOT NULL
)
```

and create a DAC over the table:

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public class UsrTrueFalse : IBqlTable
{
    #region BoolValue
    public abstract class boolValue : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Bool Value")]
    public virtual bool? BoolValue { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region TextValue
    public abstract class textValue : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDBString(3)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Text Value")]
    public virtual string TextValue { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

and then add a PXSelector attribute on your boolean field:

```
        #region Active
        public abstract class active : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXDefault(true)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<UsrTrueFalse.boolValue>), 
             DescriptionField = typeof(UsrTrueFalse.textValue))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Active")]
        public virtual bool? Active { get; set; }
        #endregion
```

The PXSelector ASPX markup:

```
        <px:PXSelector ID="edActive" runat="server" DataField="Active" DataSourceID="ds" Size="XS" DisplayMode="Text">
            <AutoCallBack Command="Save" Target="form">
            </AutoCallBack>
        </px:PXSelector>
```